# Jaxb @XmlAttribute in @XmlElement

Tags: jaxb

Please, as it could indicate the 'type' attribute on elements 'horaIniJornada' and 'tiempoJornadamedia'?

```
    @XmlElement(name = "tiempoJornadaMedia")
    public String getTimeJournalMedia() {
        return timeJournalMedia;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "tipo")
    public String getTypeHourInitJournal() {
        return typeHourInitJournal;
    }

<configuraciones>
  <almacen>MD</almacen>
  <cliente>MKD</cliente>
     <secciones>
        <seccion>
            <seccId>70</seccId>
            <horaIniJornada tipo="T">23:00:00</horaIniJornada>
            <tiempoJornadaMedia tipo="T">07:30:00</tiempoJornadaMedia>
        </seccion>
        <seccion>
             <seccId>71</seccId>
             <horaIniJornada tipo="T">23:00:00</horaIniJornada>
             <tiempoJornadaMedia tipo="T">07:30:00</tiempoJornadaMedia>
         </seccion>
      </secciones>
</configuraciones>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a separate class for that. Something like `TimeHournalMedia` with an `@XmlAttribute` and `@XmlValue` property. Something like:

```
@XmlValue
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

@XmlAttribute(name = "tipo")
public String getTypeHourInitJournal() {
    return typeHourInitJournal;
}
```

Then you'll have in your main class:

```
@XmlElement(name = "tiempoJornadaMedia")
public TimeHournalMedia getTimeJournalMedia() {
    return timeJournalMedia;
}
```

To get the textual content you'll do `getTimeJournalMedia().getValue()`, to get the attribute - `getTimeJournalMedia().getgetTypeHourInitJournal()`, something like that.

There are further options with MOXy [`@XmlPath`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/XPath).